# Prometheus alerts for single target out of 3 targets

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I am using prometheus to get alerts for a particular metric ie `verify__count`. I have 3 targets running and the rule is written as follows at present.

```
expr: absent(verify__count) > 0
```

The issue I am facing is, this alert is fired only when all 3 targets are down.

I want to retain this as a critical alert and add an other alert rule which notifies me if 1 or 2 targets are down (along with target names).

I was thinking on the lines of something like following for each target.

```
expr: absent(verify_count) == 0 and absent((verify_count{instance="instance1:8080"}))
```

But I have been advised against using absent and rewriting this alert for 3 instances.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the goal? What are you trying to be aware of with this alert? There might be a better way than to use `absent()`. For example, it the metric comes from an exporter, you may check whether Prometheus is able to scrape it.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I am a newbie in Prometheus.I am trying to be aware if the target is up and if it was successful in populating verify__count while running a service.
Does that answer your question?
Thanks

Comment: Okay, is it possible that the target is up but there is no `verify__count` in its metrics?

Comment: Yes. That could be a possibility.
Otherwise I guess, I could have used up{job="verify_job"} == 0

Answer (score 0):

The `absent()` function is useful to check whether a metric exists on any instance. Here is a query to check which instances lack a specific metric:

```
up{job="foo"} == 1 unless on(job, instance) verify_count
```

It works as following:

1. `up{job="foo"} == 1` makes a list of running instances for the `foo` scrape job.
2. `unless` removes from the list of running instances those, for which there ***is*** a `verify_count` metric with exactly the same `(job, instance)` labels.

What's left are the instances for which there is no corresponding `verify_count` metric, in other words - instances without this metric.